# androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView no se infla en android 5.0 para abajo pero en superiores si

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Obtengo este error "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView" al ejecutar esto, pero solo en android 5.0 o mas viejos:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_articulos, parent, false);
```

Codigo xml:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/articulosRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/contorno_cuadrado_accent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_inventario">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Codigo xml del background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#87C0D4"/>

    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="0px"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Que contiene : item_articulos.xml en su linea 41 podrìas agregarlo por favor?

Comment: la primera linea del codigo xml que puse:<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Comment: Prueba quitando : android:background="@drawable/contorno_cuadrado_accent" si funciona agrega a tu pregunta este elemento si es una imagen vectorial.

Comment: En el IDE (Android Studio) te sale algún warning o error del tipo " xxx esta disponible desde la version X pero la version minima soportada es Y"?

Comment: Al parecer quitando el background funciona, acabo de agregar el xml del background a la pregunta